# Clear the console in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is there a way to clear the console in Firefox?

In Chrome I can use...

```
console.clear()
```

(Not sure if it works for Safari or Opera though)

However I haven't been able to find a solution for Firefox. Is this type of API not yet available? Is there a workaround that doesn't require?

```
console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

Comment: `clear()` works in all browsers. Are you referring to clearing console from a script?

Comment: `console.clear()` works in Firebug, which I believe is a better developer tool in FireFox anyways

Comment: Why does this work in Firebug and not with Firefox's default developer tool? (Keep in mind it didn't occur for me to try this with Firebug on my initial post)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In firefox you can just input `clear()`. It well be done.

Here's a link to the Developer's website for Javascript console commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696634.aspx

Comment: this only works directly in the browser console and not by script.

Answer (score 16):

Keep it simple.
Better press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to clear the output in Firefox 44+. Whereas in previous versions press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

In Mac, for Chrome (`105.0.5195.102`) and firefox(`v103.0.2`) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> still works.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes to this question, `console.clear()` works in Firefox since version **48.0**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/clear

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you also want to clear via GUI of the browser.

1. Open the inspect element / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
2. click console menu
3. click the trash bin logo

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for future implementations of firefox, but still they don't want to implement it. So basically **you can't in webconsole**, but you can in *firebug*.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following shortcut depending on your OS

Windows & Linux:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  or  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for Firefox 67 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Firefox, you can use `console.clear()` or built-in helper function `clear()` to clear console screen
and `clearHistory()` to entirely clear console's command history.

Check out [more useful helper functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers)