# How to clear Firefox' console via javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I have some functions that when executed show some info with *console.log()*.

There is no problem with that.

But, some times, the console looks strange... Because that, they sent me to clear the console when pressing 'l' (letter 'L' in lowercase).

I took it as a simple task, I just needed to use *console.clear()* and all would be fine.

But... I only thought:

```
console.clear(); // doesn't work in firefox !!!
```

In chrome it works fine.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nyek1fbx/)

Does someone knows any technique to do this in firefox?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Clear Console \[Firefox\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924299/javascript-clear-console-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console is not standarized so they will have differences. Firefox offers some [helper commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Helper_commands) though:

```
clear()
```

(same as hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Chrome, and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox).

However, you can not call it programmatically. Only works in console itself. You could look into [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) instead as an option.

Comment: ```Ctrl + L``` works in Chrome, but not in Firefox, ```Alt + R``` works in the latter one.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster answer updated, thanks! (I just looked through MDN hotkey pages as well as in waybackmachine and this one isn't documented, so good catch).

Comment: Wow, I did not know `Ctrl` + `l` was working in browser console (just like in terminal).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `clear` is no longer accessible from `console` (Firebug 30+). Type `clear();` directly from `Firebug`.