# How to clear the javascript console programmatically?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

How we can clear the Console in Chrome, Firefox and other browsers.
I've tried the following commands, but none is working:

**Chrome:** `clear()`

**Firefox:** `console.clear()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear Firefox' console via javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309803/how-to-clear-firefox-console-via-javascript)

Comment: @Amadan No clearing the Console

Comment: Or [Clear JavaScript console in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Clear Console \[Firefox\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924299/javascript-clear-console-firefox)

Comment: `console.clear();` now works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 23):

For every browser it is different so you can write some script so that it will work for different browsers.
or you can use this script

```js
console.API;

if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._commandLineAPI; //chrome
} else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI; //Safari
} else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console;
}

console.API.clear();
```

so on for other browsers too.

*Note: Successfully tested (after edit, 08/2016) in Safari v9.1 for Mac OS, and Chrome v52.0 for Mac OS*

Comment: Note that this still doesn't work on chrome if _Preserve log_ is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, as of July 25, 2019, I first tried typing:

```
console.API.clear();
```

But, that gave a message in the console that: `console.API` is undefined.
So, smelling that something was probably right with the answer given above, but not exactly, I then typed the following in the console:

```
console.clear();
```

That worked, and the console was cleared and gave a message that the console had been cleared. I do not know if this would work in any other browser besides Firefox, and, of course, I only know that it worked today.

Answer (score 1):

Coming 5 years later ;-) but if it's of any use, here it is the @govind-mantri brilliant answer, in **TypeScript**, avoiding the TSLint errors/hints:

```
    private clearConsole() {

        // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
        const _console: any = console;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        let consoleAPI: any = console['API'];

        if (typeof _console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {                // Chrome
            consoleAPI = _console._commandLineAPI;

        } else if (typeof _console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') { // Safari
            consoleAPI = _console._inspectorCommandLineAPI;

        } else if (typeof _console.clear !== 'undefined') {                    // rest
            consoleAPI = _console;
        }

        consoleAPI.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.clear();
```

- Using this in chrome console is clear but make sure preservelog is unchecked in console setting.
  [image]