# How do I able to see the source code of this website www.samy.pl?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

This [website (www.samy.pl)](http://www.samy.pl) uses some technique so that no one can inspect the code 
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) or view source (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). It can detect if you have opened the console or inspector the code automatically changes.

How this is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide html source & disable right click and text copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597224/how-to-hide-html-source-disable-right-click-and-text-copy)

Comment: @Adam No, it's not the same as that site.

Comment: Press F12 to open your console. Use IE11 to fool their script.

Comment: what about if i goto More Tools>Developers Tools or (ctrl+shift+i) option on chrome this website redirect to another page so that no one can see the code of homepage. How to do it then?

Comment: The site somehow detects when you open the console, and the source changes.

Comment: have you tried it @yezzz

Comment: yep I tried. Works, just IE11 is old and the dev tools are horrible to work with. Might want to try Edge. BTW, in chrome: press F12, then in dev tools shift+ctrl+M to get the mobile view... it will show some elements of the site.

Comment: Nope, sorry that was samy.pl/code. IE11 works though

Comment: Edge works too. Developer console and everything

Comment: How can I do this to my website?

Comment: Duplicate of [Detect when “Inspect Element” is open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193700/detect-when-inspect-element-is-open/42194142#42194142)

Comment: Ctrl-U
Works every single time ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Are you using Firefox?
It dosent work on chrome.

Comment: I found [this on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/67ch5v/how_is_this_site_done/).

Answer (score 4):

You could always save the website.
In chrome open the menu -> more tools -> Save page as..

You should be able to run the html file in chrome, and use Dev Tools without it blocking you.

Comment: It would still be blocked because the code is what is being downloaded and is what is blocking it. But you WILL be able to open it in a text editor to view the code.

Comment: Yeah opening the file to see the code actually works!

Answer (score 3):

There is a `console` "clearing" API that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31261830/7024476).

Here's what I think is happening:

First, I think Google Chrome DevTools emits an event when it is open/launched.
The page author listens for this 'launch' event with the following handler logic:

1. Run a `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval` [DevTools inspection API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow)
2. Set `document.body.innerHTML` to the winky-face div
3. Also, a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) that executes a `console.clear()` before the `console.log()` of "no source for you".

I also inspected the EventListeners tab of Chrome DevTools while reading the "no source for you"-page.

Unfortunately, the two event listeners you can view don't seem to do *anything useful*:

- one returns `false`
- the other wires together forms and their associated submit actions.

Hope this helped

Comment: So they also clear their script tags, and remove any event listeners and/or callbacks that mess with the console.

Answer (score 3):

hahaha, this is a good one, you should not expect less from samy!

Now I see why people think it is the wrong answer (the source get replaced if you do otherwise)

1.Navigate to site with inspector open there you end up with "No source for you! You found easter egg #7."

2.and then check the source to find Easter egg #2:

```
view-source:https://samy.pl
```

you will see:

```
/*
No source for you! Easter egg #2
*// AFTER SOME LONG WHITE SPACES HERE  /.source.replace(/.{7}/g,function(w){document.write(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(w.replace(/ /g,'0').replace(/   /g,'1'),2)))});
```

This is the way he loads the site(by injecting js), by replacing two type of white spaces for 1 and 0 and parsing that to char code by some regex and then that to string of course :D

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(Programmiersprache)

If you paste that part to a js console, you will get the tags that loads the page.

[image]

ps. to see the rendered source, just load the page normaly and hit F12 after disabling javascript.

Have fun!

Comment: This is no longer valid.

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

 <noscript>

 <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/code/?ns=1\" />

 </noscript>

 <script>

  var YOU_FOUND_THE_SOURCE_TO_SAMY_PL = \"you are awesome!\"

  var total_easter_eggs = 21

  /*

   Thanks for playing!

   There are currently 21 Easter Eggs on this site,

   hope you've enjoyed running into a few, and perhaps

   you can find a few more!



   Your internet friend, -samy

  */

 </script>

 ...

Answer (score 1):

Create an `index.html` somewhere, containing an `<iframe src='https://samy.pl/'>`. Load it in your browser and then open devtools. You will see the source inside the iframe.

Comment: this doesn't really add to the answer does it? its just shows how you could see the websites source, but doesn't answer how to recreate this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Go to view-source:http://samy.pl which is the link of what the view source right click brings you to. It only works on Chrome I think.

If you are using chrome, go to the menu at the top right. Then go to more tools, and click developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tinkering and speculating together, my roommate succeeded in the end with quite a naïve approach.

Simply open the Chrome devtools and copy out the source before it gets replaced. Giving Chrome processes low priority and doing some heavy-lifting with your CPU (compilation or other) helps.

Chop, chop.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I have found an ***extremely*** easy way to do it.
1. Open Firefox (Chrome only shows you part of it).
2. In the URL bar, type in `javascript:alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

**New Way to find the source code! But its complicated!**
Open a new tab.
Open Devtools (Inspect Tab) 
Click On Toggle Device toolbar (the mobile like icon)
[image]

Click on "No Throttling" to slow down the page loading time
[image]

Select "Low - Tier Mobile"
[image]

Open the page!
When you see the icons appear on the page, you can now see the source code! :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry very late
but i think i have the answer

He used this [node package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect)
to which he has [contributed](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/commits?author=samyk) and [forked](https://github.com/samyk/devtools-detect) too

the package docs say that it wont work if the devtools are undocked

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use the developer tools in almost all the browsers. Just Press F12 and the developer tools section will be there.

Thanks

Comment: That might also be blocked by the code on the website because if right click is blocked, and those keyboard commands are blocked, then F12 is probably blocked too.

Comment: F12 does work, it brings the dev tools, but the site detects this and loads other content. Sites have limited control over browsers. Why do you think they're limiting js xss.