# Delete Firefox JavaScript console history?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How do I clear the command history of Firefox's JavaScript console? Clearing all history, cookies, cache, etc., doesn't clear the JavaScript console history, nor does [`clear()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25924299/1429450).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enter this in the console:

> `clearHistory()`
>
> *New in Firefox 39.* Just like a normal command line, the console command line [remembers the commands you've typed](/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Command_history). Use this function to clear the console's command history.